# FTP and SQL database

Tags: sql, ftp, firewall

Sorry if this is a silly question, I do not have much enterprise programming experience so please bear with me.

I have a server that has an SQL database on it, and a program that is looking to write to that database. Between the program and the database there is a firewall that will only allow FTP connections through (I cannot change this).

Can I write to the SQL database using only the FTP port that the firewall allows through?

Comment: You can run your database on the FTP port, I guess, but that's a horrible idea. The firewall (and associated network access policies) are there for a reason. Make your case to the relevant managers. The extra review may benefit the project (personally, I would not want a database accessible directly from outside, big fan of three-tier architecture).

Comment: It will sound strange, but the server is ours, the hardware on the local network is ours, but the network is not. The only thing they have made available to us is the FTP port. Again, I apologize for my ignorance but could you point me towards a work around? Just a term to start with that I can google will do.